# LaTeX two different page numbers on the same page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want to get two different page numbers on the same page in `LaTeX`. For example, I want to have overall page numbers in the footer and within chapter page numbers in the header. I wonder how to get this one. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
% Document Class
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{Special}{%
\fancyhf{}% Clear fancy header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\fancyhead[r]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[r]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}


% Begin Document
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{Special}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Intro1}
\subsection{Intro2}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Intro1}
\subsection{Intro2}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper

% End Document
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I introduce a `\newcounter{pagecntr}[chapter]` which will be set to zero for every new chapter. I did not manage to set it directly to 1. That's why I needed to do the ugly `\setcounter{temp}{\thepagecntr}\stepcounter{temp}\thetemp` every time I want to print it. I guess, there are better approaches, but well... doesn't matter, it works.

The final trick is to use the package `everyshi` which increments my new counter by one for every page.

```
 % arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\newcounter{pagecntr}[chapter]
\EveryShipout{\stepcounter{pagecntr}}
\newcounter{temp}

\fancypagestyle{Special}{%
    \fancyhf{}% Clear fancy header/footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.7pt}
    \fancyhead[r]{Page \setcounter{temp}{\thepagecntr}\stepcounter{temp}\thetemp}
    \fancyfoot[r]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\begin{document}    
    \tableofcontents    
    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{Special}     
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \section{Introduction}  
    \subsection{Intro1}
    \subsection{Intro2} 
    \blindtext[1]
    \section{Material \& Method}    
    \blindmathpaper 
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
    \section{Introduction}  
    \subsection{Intro1}
    \subsection{Intro2} 
    \blindtext[1]   
    \section{Material \& Method}    
    \blindmathpaper 
\end{document}
```

[image]

NB: I would recommend to write something like `\thetemp\ of Ch.\ \thechapter` as two numbers on one page will be confusing if not explained.

Comment: Thanks @LaRiFaRi for your nice answer. Is this possible to have page numbers in header for some chapters and for others no page numbers in header?

Comment: @MYaseen208 just define a `\fancypagestyle{evenMoreSpecial}{...` with empty header and switch to `\pagestyle{evenMoreSpecial}` where ever you need. If you want something automatic, you have to do a follow up question. Please always keep in mind that your readers will have to understand your numbering. Sounds like a bit too much what you are doing right now. But well, you will have your reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an additional suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr`. The pagestyle `scrheadings` is defined without the chapter pagenumber in the header and an alias `Normal` is set for this pagestyle. Then `scrheadings` is cloned to page style `Special`adding the chapter pagenumber in the header. The `onbackground` hook for `@everystyle@` is used to step the chapter pagenumber on every page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\newcounter{pagecntr}[chapter]

\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\usepackage[
  automark,
  markcase=upper,
  headsepline=.7pt,
  footsepline=.7pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{@everystyle@}{onbackground={\stepcounter{pagecntr}}}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage]{}
\refoot{\pagemark}
\rofoot{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}%
}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\DeclareNewPageStyleAlias{Normal}{scrheadings}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{Special}{%
  \rohead{Page~\thepagecntr}%
  \rehead{Page~\thepagecntr}%
}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents    
\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Introduction}  
\subsection{Intro1}
\subsection{Intro2} 
\blindtext[1]
\section{Material \& Method}    
\blindmathpaper 

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\pagestyle{Special}
\section{Introduction}  
\subsection{Intro1}
\subsection{Intro2} 
\blindtext[1]   
\section{Material \& Method}    
\blindmathpaper 

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\pagestyle{Normal}
\section{Introduction}  
\subsection{Intro1}
\subsection{Intro2} 
\blindtext[1]   
\section{Material \& Method}    
\blindmathpaper 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the code which is needed for your output?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Oh sorry. Now the code is added.